# HoughLines error: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I am attempting to use HoughLines to identify the horizontal and vertical lines in [this image, here it is after the thresholding and other operations shown in the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4ddq.png) so I can draw them in black and remove them. here is my code so far:

```
)

src_no_bg = 255 - cv2.absdiff(src, bg)

maxValue = 255
thresh = 240
```

however the HoughLines line of code keeps on returning this error

```
only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters you provided to the function is incorrect as stated by the documentation for openCV:

```
cv2.HoughLines(image, rho, theta, threshold[, lines[, srn[, stn]]]) → lines
```

There is also no need to include the math library as numpy library has its own pi function.

The function should be used as below:

```
lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 0, 0, 0)
```